# I want to override on AllowCreate, How to override this method in TelerikSchedule with Blazor?

Tags: telerik, blazor, blazor-server-side, c#-6.0, telerik-scheduler

When AllowCreate="true", its automatically opened own appointment addDialog?. I want Stop that and want move custom page(My own page).

I added screenshot about razor [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZl0k.png)file. Please see that and help me!
Thank You!.

Comment: Does something like this work for you.  https://github.com/telerik/blazor-ui/tree/master/scheduler/custom-edit-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution like below for my question.

Razor file code:

```
<TelerikScheduler
           Data="@Appointments"
           Date="@StartDate"
           OnItemClick="@OnItemClick"
           @bind-View="@CurrView"
           DateChanged="@DateChangedHandler"
           Height="480px">

               <SchedulerResources>
                   <SchedulerResource Field="ManagerName" Data="@Managers" />
               </SchedulerResources>

               <SchedulerViews> 

               <SchedulerWeekView
                   StartTime="@DayStart"
                   EndTime="@DayEnd"                  
                   SlotDuration="30"
                   SlotDivisions="5"/>

               </SchedulerViews>

           </TelerikScheduler>
```

And also, I created method for automatically generate slot in cs file

```
private void SlotGenerated() 
    {        
        DateTime st = new DateTime(2022, 6, 1, 8, 0, 0);
        DateTime ed = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(2);
        int i = 1;
        while (st <= ed)
        {
            if (i == 6) { i = 1;  }

            AppointmentDto appointment = new AppointmentDto();

            appointment.Id = 0;
            appointment.Start = st;
            appointment.End = st.AddMinutes(6);
            appointment.Name = "SLOT " + i;
            appointment.IsAllDay = false;
            appointment.ManagerName = "1";


            Appointments.Add(appointment);

            st = st.AddMinutes(6);
            ++i;`enter code here`
        }
        UIStateChanged();
    }
```